# Output Div ID multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I create with JavaScript / JQuery IDs, which I can output afterwards with HTML.
Problem is that I can output each ID only once.
How can I implement that the ID can be output as often as I want?
I have created an example where I want to output the ID `output` 2 times.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```js
if($('#output').length){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Example output';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Load</div>
<p>Here is more page content</p>
<div id="output">Load</div>
```

I also created a fiddle if it helps more.
https://jsfiddle.net/dfaLpv0h/

Comment: dom id is unique, you can use class.

Comment: id attributes *have* to be unique in the DOM. Use a common class on multiple elements instead, but remember you'll need to loop through them all.

Comment: `$("[id=output]")` - but much better to not have duplicate IDs - even Chrome now complains about these in the console.

Comment: You can have multiple `id`s in certain circumstances. [w3c id-attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute): "This specification doesn't preclude an element having multiple IDs, if other mechanisms (e.g. DOM Core methods) can set an element's ID in a way that doesn't conflict with the id attribute."

Comment: @kmgt nice link - it says "an element [can have] multiple IDs" - not "multiple elements can have the same ID" which it precludes by status it's the "elements unique identifier".  I guess it means `<div id="a" id="b">` is ok, but still `<div id="a"><div id="a">` is not ok.

Comment: @freedomn-m I guess you are right. But how to manipulate the DOM and append another `id`!? And how to work with a second `id` attribute... The definition makes no sence.